# AngularJS taking JSON from nodejs API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I got some kind of strange question.
My nodejs api works with mongodb.
Angular is requesting data from nodejs by JSON.
I use Webstorm 11 to launch Angular App.
So, then I'm doing **ng-repeat** using that JSON and get this:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined
    at arguments.(anonymous function) (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2001:19)
    at m.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:138:399)
    at m.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2016:23)
    at m.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:341)
    at m.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2079:22)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:21:44
        at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:295)
    at Ac.c (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:20:468)
    at Object.Ac.ia.resumeBootstrap (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:21:357)
    at maybeBootstrap (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:569:11)
```

and this:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined
    at arguments.(anonymous function) (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2001:19)
    at m.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:138:399)
    at m.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2016:23)
    at m.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:141:341)
    at m.scopePrototype.$apply (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:2079:22)
    at g (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:94:139)
    at t (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:98:260)
    at XMLHttpRequest.u.onload (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:99:297)
```

for every element in ng-repeat.
Result page works fine, but this errors in console are not good.

Then I tried to use this JSON:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json

Working with this JSON not throwing any errors..
So thats how I realize that my JSON not "good enough" :D Maybe I need to put some kind of headers? In attached pictures you can compare JSON's that I'm using.

p.s. One more strange thing: when i'm executing my index.html file in browser without webstorm (file:///Users/rustem/Dropbox/octomoney/index.html) - no errors occur in console and the app works fine!

**JSON's**:

```
    curl -i -X GET http://localhost:3000/getData?collection=expenses
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    X-Powered-By: Express
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Content-Encoding: UTF-8
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 1009
    ETag: W/"3f1-Y7uhK30COBeAh0OJQ4Upzg"
    Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:49:25 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive

    {"result":"1","message":"Request completed","data":[{"name":"Прочее","icon":"all_inclusive","color":"#b7cfd9","subCategories":"Ebay & Ali"},{"name":"Автомобиль","icon":"directions_car","color":"#63a3d2","subCategories":"Ремонт"}]}


    curl -i -X GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    x-amz-id-2: I2wao57Or1Ib/0Ox9Bp/g5xNrlqqxbK/7kti+YjugN3974z1soOeOMhH+e5mw2Pz
    x-amz-request-id: 7B8334962BA70A53
    Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:44:56 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Content-Encoding: UTF-8
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Jan 2015 16:20:44 GMT
    ETag: "f059fbba22678ca58a51d7b8d1e99061"
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 946
    Server: AmazonS3

    {
    "city_name": "New York",
    "country": "US",
    "days": [
    {
    "datetime": 1420390800000,
    "icon": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/sun.svg",
    "high": 68,
    "low": 37
    },
    {
    "datetime": 1420736400000,
    "icon": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/sun.svg",
    "high": 59,
    "low": 32
    }
```

how I use **ng-repeat:**

```
    <body ng-app="octomoney">
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="getExpensesController">
            <div ng-repeat="expense in expenses.data" align="center">
                <h4>{{ expense.name }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/getExpensesService.js"></script>
    </body>
```

**app.js**:

```
    var app = angular.module('octomoney', []);
```

**mainController.js**:

```
    app.controller('getExpensesController', ['$scope', 'getExpensesService', function ($scope, getExpensesService) {
        getExpensesService.success(function (data) {
            $scope.expenses = data;
        });
    }]);
```

**getExpensesService.js**:

```
    app.factory('getExpensesService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        //return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/forecast-api/forecast.json')
            return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/getData?collection=expenses&queryBuilder=1==1')
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                return err;
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: I don't see attached picture. Link us your HTML where you perform your ng-repeat, a part of your json file to check the dara format, and how you load it in your controller

Comment: The reason behind this error is ...you have injected getExpensesService in getExpensesController but you havnt add the ExpensesService module in angular.module('octomoney', []);

Comment: @Banik no, not helped.
Again, with another JSON works fine(no errors).

Comment: @Waltrat, sorry edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that AngularJS Batarnang causing this problem.

Details here: https://github.com/angular/batarang/issues/285